# CCD IK algorithm going horribly wrong

Tags: inverse-kinematics

I'm trying to implement the Cyclic Coordinate Descent algorithm described here:

http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~15464-s13/assignments/assignment2/jlander_gamedev_nov98.pdf

So first of all,  I'm passing in the starting position bone which the CCD algorithm should stop at and the endPos which is the end-effector bone essentially. So in this instance, startPos could be taken from the **Left_Clavicle** bone and the endPos could be the **Left_Hand**. I also pass in the target position and a model object to be able to update the hierarchy.

Here is my attempt at the CCD:

```
void ComputeCCD(Model * model,glm::vec3 target, Bone * startPos, AnimNode * endPos)
{
    glm::vec3 rootPos,curEnd,desiredEnd,targetVector,curVector,crossResult;
    double cosAngle,turnAngle,turnDeg;
    int tries;

    Bone * currentBone = endPos->m_parent;
    tries = 0;

    do
    {
        rootPos = GetPosition(currentBone->m_globalTransform);
        // POSITION OF THE END EFFECTOR
        curEnd = GetPosition(endPos->m_globalTransform);
        // DESIRED END EFFECTOR POSITION
        desiredEnd = target;
        float distSq = DistSquare(curEnd,desiredEnd);
        // SEE IF I AM ALREADY CLOSE ENOUGH
        if (distSq > IK_POS_THRESH)
        {
            // CREATE THE VECTOR TO THE CURRENT EFFECTOR POS
            curVector = curEnd - rootPos;

            // CREATE THE DESIRED EFFECTOR POSITION VECTOR
            targetVector= target - rootPos;

            cosAngle = glm::dot(targetVector,curVector);
            turnAngle = glm::acos((float)cosAngle); 
            turnDeg = glm::degrees(turnAngle); 
            //Get axis of rotation
            crossResult = glm::cross(targetVector,curVector);

            //currentBone->m_localTransform *= glm::rotate(glm::mat4(1.0f),          (float)turnDeg,crossResult);

            // IF THE DOT PRODUCT RETURNS 1.0, I DON'T NEED TO ROTATE AS IT IS 0 DEGREES
            if (cosAngle < 0.99999)
            {
                if (crossResult.z > 0.0f) // IF THE Z ELEMENT IS POSITIVE, ROTATE CLOCKWISE
                {

                    currentBone->m_localTransform = glm::rotate(currentBone->m_globalTransform,-(float)turnDeg,crossResult);
                }
                else if (crossResult.z < 0.0f) // ROTATE COUNTER CLOCKWISE
                {
                    currentBone->m_localTransform =  glm::rotate(currentBone->m_globalTransform,(float)turnDeg,crossResult);
                }

             }
             if (currentBone->m_name == startPos->m_name) 
             {
              currentBone = endPos->m_parent; 
              // START OF THE CHAIN, RESTART
             }
             else
             {
                 currentBone = currentBone->m_parent;
             }
               model->UpdateHierarchy(currentBone);
             }

      } while (tries++ < MAX_IK_TRIES && DistSquare(curEnd, desiredEnd) > IK_POS_THRESH);
}
```

So I have a tracker which I can move around and pass into this method. Whenever I try to run it I get the following error. The arm folds in on itself :(

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it by replacing

```
 currentBone->m_localTransform = glm::rotate(currentBone->m_globalTransform,-  (float)turnDeg,crossResult);
```

with

```
 glm::mat4 rotation = glm::axisAngleMatrix(crossResult, (float)turnAngle);

 currentBone->m_localTransform *= rotation;
```